# Tensorflow GPU - device interconnect, stream executor with strength 1 edge matrix?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a box with 4 Nvidia K80 GPUs. I'm running Tensorflow 2. When I run a training session (`tf.keras` => `model.fit()`), I see the following log statements:

```
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1102] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1108]      0 1 2 3
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1121] 0:   N Y N N
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1121] 1:   Y N N N
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1121] 2:   N N N Y
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1121] 3:   N N Y N
```

## Question:

What is the meaning of that grid, and how much I possibly leverage it?

---

For what it's worth, my model looks like the following, and I cannot get it to use more than a single GPU:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size, emb_dim, mask_zero=mask_zero),
    tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(lstm_dim)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(dense_dim, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation='softmax')
])
```

Comment: Did I answer your question?

Comment: Yes. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, "Y" (YES) denotes in multi-GPU setup if the GPU has direct memory access from one another and to the network adapters, solid state drives and such. It is called [GPU direct](https://developer.nvidia.com/gpudirect) and how much you leverage it depends on the particular task and `tf.distribute.Strategy`.

To understand the impact, you'd have to profile your code under normal setup and then with the GPU direct. In general, the more CPU overhead is a bottleneck for you, the more you could potentially benefit from this tech.

"Potentially", because in practice it depends on the nature of the task. If the CPU if primarily busy with launching kernels (because you used GRU layer with ReLU activation - and this one does not have cuDNN-optimised version), then GPU direct can't help you in any way.

However, if the GPUs need to exchange information or read often from IO, then you're off to a good start.